# Which connection JAR to use for Sybase DBMS?

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, jar, sybase

In our project, we are going to use Sybase as the DBMS in the JSF and Hibernate web based environment. However, we haven't decided which jar to use and would be best appropriate for the Sybase connection. *jconn2* and *jconn3* are available as jar but we don't know which one of them is working more reliable, secure and efficient. (if any other known jar is more useful and appropriate, it will be also welcomed). I am waiting you fellows' precious and invaluable ideas and experiences.
Yours sincerely...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the differences between jconn2 and jconn3 is implementation of DateTime type of columns and If I am correct, bugs  fixed on jconn3 for DateTime types. And a bit slower than jconn2 for this type.

An important point is which version of sybase will you use? Because engine's have been rewritten for sybase 15.x version.

Comment: we are using Sybase 15.0.3 ASE